# List all records on main page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to list all records from the database in the main page.

Model and controllers were both created properly (I suspect) since using the following code and pointing to proper address (`http://localhost:3000/subdomainw1s`) lists all the records:

in /app/views/subdomainw1s/index.html.erb:

```
   <h1>subdomain word 1</h1>
    <ol class="subdomainw1">
      <% @subdomainw1s.each do |sdw1| %>
        <li>
          <%= sdw1.blognamew1 %>
             </li>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
```

However, attempting to past the same code in `/app/views/home/index.html.erb` results in an error message (**"undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"**) complaining about:

```
<% @subdomainw1s.each do |sdw1| %>
```

Clearly, rails doesn't know what to do with this model under the home page.. no?

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

there is at least two more "codeless" options

convert it to (empty) array

```
..@subdomainw1s.to_a.each do |sdw1|..
```

or use method `try`

```
..@subdomainw1s.try(:each) do |sdw1|..
```

Comment: Tried these options too (beyond prasad's method which worked great. However, the page was empty (at least no error messages were shown).

Comment: copy some code to another place is not the good practice according to DRY philosophy... you can use partial in that case. methods i proposed give possibility not to receive error when you have empty or nil @subdomainw1s without wrapping code into if-end

Answer (score 0):

copy the code to collect the subdomains from 'index' in subdomains controller to 'index' in home controller.

Comment: Worked great, and makes sense - For the app/views/home/index.html.erb (namely, the 'main page') to 'know' about this model, it's controller needs a def index pointing to said model. Hope this helps future RoR'ers.